# How do I get field data in Magento from a custom module?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend-framework, magento

I'm very new to Magento development (this is my first module). The purpose of this module is to fix some problems that we are having with the original one, while not making any changes to the model/controller. I am modifying this existing template, but I cannot seem to find a way to retrieve fields. The template is using:

```
$this->getChildHtml('submit_button');
```

to submit the data. This is ultimately making a call to a javascript/ajax function that pretty much leaves me at a dead end. I'm simply wanting to get the values of, let's say:

```
<textarea name="thing[other]" .../>
```

How would I retrieve that value so that my Model may manipulate it? Overriding the controller is not an option, this page is essentially a duplicate of another that uses the same controllers. The functionality of that controller is desired for that one, just not desired for this one.

or

My other option is to override the template. My problem with that is that the original module is using an observer to override the template, and I'm not sure how to override that.

Comment: You won't check for posted data in a template but in a controller – which you need to create to perform any task…

Comment: @feeela I've looked at the controllers for sales_order and custommodulesales_order and cannot find anything related to grabbing the post data.

Comment: Inside some action in a class which extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action`: `$this->getRequest()->getPost();`

Comment: The module does have a class which extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action but it does not handle the post data at all. That I guess means that they didn't override it to begin with. It also occurs to me that I may not override that function, as it is still being used by another part of the site. @feeela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a controller and set the form action to post to this controller. You can then access the post data by calling :

`$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();`

Comment: Interestingly this template doesn't use post, or even forms at all. It's calling an ajax/js script and bypassing the magento module completely. I'm modifying the template to include a form and changing the submit properties so that it will just post to my module. Thanks.

Comment: If you are modifying a third party extension, it s not unusual to find dirty code here and there. Good thing you want to learn the proper way even if its surely a bit more time consuming

Comment: Little worried about the time crunch, but I'm working to get it down properly. I'm basically an intern, so I would like to get as much out of this as I can.